# Closure of a set defined using a function

Tags: general-topology

I have the following set in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$$
S=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : f(x_2)<0\} \neq \varnothing
$$
for some continuous function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Can we say that the closure of $S$ is given by 
$$
\overline S=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : f(x_2)\leq 0\}
$$ 
Please help me as I am new to set theory...

Comment: What is the closure ? The closure is the smallest closed set which contains your set.

Comment: Is your function continuous?

Comment: Is $S$ non-empty?

Comment: I have accepted the edits by @ChoF

Comment: **[Counterexample]** Let $f(x)=-x^2(x^2-1)$. Then $S=\mathbb{R}\times f^{-1}((-\infty,0))=\mathbb{R}\times\bigl((-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)\bigr)$. But $\overline{S}=\mathbb{R}\times\bigl((-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)\bigr)$ is not the same as $\mathbb{R}\times f^{-1}((-\infty,0])=\mathbb{R}\times\bigl((-\infty,-1]\cup\{0\}\cup[1,\infty)\bigr)$.

Comment: In my opinion, this question (edited one) makes sense. Students who study general topology or elementary real analysis may encounter this kind of question and come to a false conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer addresses the *original* question.)

As @TPace suggests, if $f$ admits a point of discontinuity, then it's not necessarily true.

Consider the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & x < 0 \\ 1 & x \ge 0\end{cases}$.  Since $0$ is not in the range of $f$, $f(x) < 0$ is equivalent to $f(x) \le 0$.  Can you continue?

> \begin{align} S &= \{(x_1,x_2) \mid f(x_2)<0\} \\ &= \{(x_1,x_2) \mid f(x_2) \le 0\} \\ &= \Bbb{R} \times (-\infty,0) \\ \bar{S} &= \Bbb{R} \times (-\infty,0] \ne S \end{align}

Comment: What if $f$ is continuous and $S$ is nonempty as suggested by @ChoF

Comment: @bersou Claim: $$S = \{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : f(x_2)<0\} = \Bbb{R} \times f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$$ has closure $$\Bbb{R} \times f^{-1}((-\infty,0])=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : f(x_2)\leq 0\}.$$  Your claim now becomes true once you can prove $$\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : f(x_2)\leq 0\} \subseteq \overline S.$$

Comment: So you mean that we already have $\bar S\subseteq\mathbb{R}\times f^{-1}((-\infty, 0])$ and we are looking for the opposite inequality? I can not see that, can you help?

Comment: @bersou First, from definition of $S$, $$S\subseteq\mathbb{R}\times f^{-1}((-\infty, 0]).$$  Since $\bar S$ is the *smallest* closed set containing $S$, you have the set inclusion in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let f be the continuous zero function. Thus S is empty.
However P = { (x,y) : f(y) <= 0 } is the whole plain.
Consequently P /= $\overline S.$

A continuous counter example with a not empty S is
f(x) = 0 if x < 0;  f(x) = -x if 0 <= x.

Are you afraid of asking a question directly?
For example, "Is the closure of S ...?"

Comment: What if $S$ is not empty?

Comment: @bersou.  See edit.